# Spring Boot log to file - works on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, spring-boot

On Spring Boot (1.2.2) my application.properties looks like:

```
logging.level.*=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/app.log
```

On my Windows machine it works (writes to C:/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/app.log).
On Ubuntu (under Tomcat 8)its not working.
I have other webapps on the same Tomcat which write logs to /usr/share/tomcat8/logs with no problem.
I even  tried to create the 'app.log' file myself and set its permissions to 777 just for the testing but its not worked.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Your log file is not being created? File is created but no message is being logged? Error level is not properly reflected?

Comment: @SayemAhmed log file is not being created... if I try to create it myself so no content being writes to it...

Comment: Does tomcat have proper permission for that file (the user under which the tomcat is running)? Did you check?

Comment: @SayemAhmed Tomcat is running under root and these are the permissions for 'logs' directory: 
drwxr-xr-x   root root